# Can you submit an app to Google Play as a partnership and not an individual?

Tags: android, google-play

Maybe this isn't the right place to ask this (if so, please point me in the right direction).

I know iOS doesn't allow partnerships. You're either an individual or a corporation.  Is Google Play (or other app stores) the same way?

When I start the process to make a developer account, it either wants to use my existing google plus account or have me make a new one (that also wants things like name and birthday).

Our partnership has a "doing business as" name that I want the app to be listed under. Is this impossible?

Comment: There is a "Developer name" field on Google Developer Console. That is essentially the display name for your company on the app.

Comment: I know in iOS if you put anything other than your legal name, they kill your app. Is google play not the same?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. When I started (4 years ago) I had the same approach as you. Signed up as an individual, but listed the app under our business name.